# Definition initial segment, chain and cut

Tags: order-theory

[image: set theory Charles C. Pinter]

Hello, I am recently in this new topic and I am not sure how to interpret the initial segment and chain definitions, someone could clarify my doubt with this example. why is it chain? why is it initial segment?

The figure represents a partially ordered class with six elements. Note that  $ \{a, b, c\} $ and $ \{d, e, b, c\}$ are chains of $A$; $S_e = \{b, c, f \} $ is the initial segment determined by $e$; if $L =\{a, b, c\}$ and $U =\{d, e, f\}$, then $\{L, U\}$ is a cut.

Definition Let $A$ be a partially ordered class and suppose $a ∈ A$. The initial segment of $A$ determined by $a$ is the class $S_a$, defined as follows:

$S_a= \{x \in A: x \prec a \} $

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this other than just writing down the definition and explaining how the three elements make a chain, etc. Is there a particular point where this strategy failed for you? (I'm not trying to be condescending, I remember as a student sometimes it was scary to check against a definition you've only seen once or twice.)

Comment: For the case of initial segment, in the example  $ S_e= \{b,c,f\} $, I was trying this  $ S_a= \{b,c\} $ ,  $ S_d= \{e,f\} $,  $ S_b= \{c\} $,  $ S_c= \varnothing $ but I'm not sure, I'd like that you help me with this, using the definition. @AsafKaragila

Comment: $L= \{a,b,c,e,f\} $ and $U=\{d\}$ is a cut? @AsafKaragila